# Django HttpResponseRedirect either crashes the site or shows a blank page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have this issues with Django forms where on each refresh the form would resubmit the last input into the database I tried working with "HttpResponseRedirect" but it would either crash the site or show a blank page.

Heres the code of views.py:

```
def page(request) : 
    employe = Employe.objects.all()
    if request.method =='POST' :
      form = EmployeForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect("")
    else :
      form = EmployeForm()
    return render(request,'hello.html',{'employe':employe,'form':form,})
```

Form template:

```
              <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Ajouter</button>
              </form>
```

Forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import Employe

class EmployeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employe
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: you have no `else` condition for `if form.is_valid():` so the view will return None result in a blank page. Because you refresh the page(resubmit POST) without sending the form with request data it make the form invalid

Comment: Can you please also share the template? I think you should render form fields in loop and there errors also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide some success url inside HttpResponseRedirect as:

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect("/success/")
```

Or you can call the name of view as:

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("some_path_name"))
```

To redirect on the same page use:

```py
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```